# Proof that $n^\frac{n}{2} \in \mathcal{O}(n!)$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, factorial, computational-complexity

In the context of Algorithm's time complexity, I'm trying to proof the following

$n^\frac{n}{2} \in \mathcal{O}(n!)$

I'm aware of the following inequalities:

$\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^\frac{n}{2} \leq n! \leq n^n, \quad n\geq1$

but I don't manage to use them to proof the original statement.

Appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want

$n^\frac{n}{2} \in O(n!)
$.

We know that
$n! \gt (\frac{n}{e})^n
$
so if
$n^\frac{n}{2}
\le (\frac{n}{e})^n
$
for all large enough $n$
we are done.

But this is equivalent to
$n^\frac{1}{2}
\le \frac{n}{e}
$
or
$n^{1/2}
\ge e
$
or
$n \ge e^2
$
which is certainly true for
$n \ge 9$
since
$e < 3$.

This can be used
to show that
$n^{cn} = O(n!)$
for any $0 < c < 1$.

Note.

$n! \gt (\frac{n}{e})^n
$
follows by induction from
$(1+\frac1{n})^n < e$
which can be proved in an elementary way
by showing that
$(1+\frac1{n})^n$
is an increasing sequence
which has $e$ as its limit.

Comment: Beautiful and simple. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

By Stirling's approximation, $\ln n! = n \ln n - n + \Theta(\ln n)$

That is, $\exists c_1$  $\hspace{20pt} n \ln n - n + c_1\ln n  \leq \ln n!$ 
That is, $\exists c_1$ $\hspace{20pt} n(\ln n - 1) + c_1\ln n  \leq \ln n!$

Let $f(n)=n^{n/2}$

Since
$ \hspace{27pt} \ln (f(n)) = n ((\ln n)/2) \leq n(\ln n - 1)$ holds for all $n \geq 8$

We have, $ \hspace{13pt}   \ln (f(n)) \leq \ln n! \hspace{20pt}$ for all appropriately large $n$

And thus, $f(n) \in \mathcal{O}(n!)$

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elementary proof that does not require any calculus knowledge.

For even $n$, we can rewrite $n!$, from $1\times2\times\cdots\times n$, as

$$\underbrace{(1n)(2(n-1))(3(n-2))\cdots\left(\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)\right)}_{\frac{n}{2}\text{ terms}}$$

As we can see, all of the brackets that are being multiplied are in the form $(1+k)(n-k)$, which we can expand into $n+(n-1)k-k^2=n+k(n-1-k)$. This implies that when $0\leq k\leq n-1$, $(1+k)(n-k)\geq n$. Here, $0\leq k\leq\frac{1}{2}n$, so this condition is satisfied. Hence, we know that

$$n!\geq n^\frac{n}{2}$$

for even $n$.

For odd $n$, we can rewrite $n!$ as

$$\underbrace{(1n)(2(n-1))(3(n-2))\cdots\left(\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)\right)}_{\frac{n-1}{2}\text{ terms}}\cdot \frac{n+1}{2}$$

Similarly, we can see that each of the pairs of numbers in the brackets is larger than or equal to $n$, so we have

$$n!\geq n^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\cdot\frac{n+1}{2}>n^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$$

For $n>4$, we have $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}>1$, which imples $n!>n^{\frac{n}{2}}$.

Hence,

$$n^{\frac{n}{2}}\in O(n!)$$